# SQL Server 2012 Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a very big view that uses many tables and other views. When I select * from this big view, I get  an error

> error converting data type varchar to numeric

The problem is I don't know where exactly it happens. Do I have to drill into all the involved objects, or there is a way to know where exactly is the problem?

Comment: There must be a `UNION`, `JOIN`, or `CASE` expression which leads to that error. Unfortunately, you have no easy way of pointing it out. I suggest you post the `VIEW` definition.

Comment: Can you script out the view and run it? It may point you towards the line of code that is causing the issue. Otherwise, can you view the estimated execution plan? The issue sounds like it's going to be in a join somewhere as it's trying to compare a varchar to a numeric field and trying to convert the varchar and failing.

Comment: @RichBenner I did it and it does not point the line, which makes me think it's in one of the joined objects.

Comment: Post your SQL used in your view

Comment: remove your joins in order and see when it starts working, once you know which sub view is broken then do the same with that view until you find the answer.

Comment: If the task of going through the query is daunting maybe you can work backwards through the output table, look for all the numeric fields get a list and then backtrack each one through the query, the original field is a varchar obviously so get a list of varchar fields to numeric fields using the query and the output table and it may lead you to the problem statement(s)

Answer (score 0):

it could also be a function like:

```
declare @pippo numeric
set @pippo=null
select ISNULL(@pippo, 'x')
```

this will raise same conversion error

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Take the definition of the view, and make it into a SELECT statement.  Then remove half the columns and run it, keep removing columns until the problem goes away.  If it goes away, then add them back until you find the problem.
If it doesn't go away, then the problem is in a join.